# Crop image not working properly in IE

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer

[image]I am using crop.js for cropping image in my application but its slider not working in IE.
I can't resize the image.

This is the code for resizing in js

```
this.imgResize = function (scale) {

        var img = this.eles.img,
            imgInfo = this.imgInfo,
            oldScale = imgInfo.s;

        imgInfo.s = scale || imgInfo.s;

        img.css({
            width: imgInfo.w * imgInfo.s,
            height: imgInfo.h * imgInfo.s
        });

        // Move Image Based on Size Changes
        this.imgMove({
            t: -((imgInfo.h * oldScale) - (imgInfo.h * imgInfo.s)) / 2,
            l: -((imgInfo.w * oldScale) - (imgInfo.w * imgInfo.s)) / 2
        });
    };
```

Answer (score -1):

Internet Explorer is not the best browser to do jquery. IE does not have right plugins or codecs to do this type of code. I would recommend using one of these:

Get the latest version of these browsers:

**Google Chrome (Version 35.0.1916.153 m)**

**Mozilla Firefox (Version 30.0)**

Thanks,

Albert

Comment: This has nothing to do with plugins or codecs. The code is jQuery, i.e. JavaScript. If it isn't working correctly in IE, then there is a bug in the code and can be fixed.

Comment: I am saying to replace IE with another browser like Firefox or Chrome.

Comment: That is not a solution.

Comment: Sorry, thought I could help.